# Pass values from backend to frontend in polymer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, polymer, jinja2, template-engine

I am building a web app using Google App Engine and Polymer.

Before using polymer I used to pass my values to the frontend using jinja2 templating:

```
def render_str(self, template, **params):
    t = JINJA_ENV.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

def render(self, template, **kw):
    self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw)))
```

-

```
{% for note in notes %}
<div class="note">
    <div>{{note.title}}</div>
    <div>{{note.created}}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This works fine for the main page but all imported polymer files are out of the scope of these passed values.

**How can I pass values from my backend to my polymer forms?** Is there a way to get my imported polymer files in the same scope as my main page or is there an alternate template engine I could use?
I saw that polymer has its own [templating and data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html) but I could not find a way to fill these with values from my backend.

Comment: http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-docs/index.html#core-ajax is one option. Another is to make ajax calls and populate your elements when they return data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data binding is pretty simple in Polymer. Use the Polymer Expressions, e.g.

```
var testString = "Hello"

<div id="test" class="test">{{testString}}</div>

document.getElementById("test").testString = "Whats up?";
```

To pass a value from your main page to a component, you can either use the attribution model, e.g.

```
<my-polymer-component id="test" mydata="Hello" />

<polymer-element attributes="mydata ...">
```

or just assign it to the Polymer element itself:

```
document.getElementById("test").mydata = "Whats up";
```

The variables are auto populated into the Polymer element. Reading from it would be the same - as long they are exposed on the element itself or even defined in the actual Polymer object:

```
Polymer('my-polymer-component', {
 mydata: 'foo',

 ready: function() { ... }
});
```